# How to remove showinfo youtube player?

Tags: javascript, html, markup

Question on how this is pulled off

example at this page: https://genius.com/Xxxtentacion-sad-lyrics

They are able to hide title youtube button and related videos via embed frame which isn't possible anymore is there special javascript exploit to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
showinfo is deprecated. You can set `modestlogo=1` which will:

> prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. Note that a small YouTube 
>   text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's
>   mouse pointer hovers over the player.

But to completely hide that the video is coming from Youtube, I don't think that's possible anymore.

Comment: yeah, that said the website is using youtube embed via an exploit with javascript embed params they must have left i was wondering if anyone knew